# Instagram API storing images from a tag in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, api, instagram

I am trying to store all images on instagram from a particular tag in my database. My code calls the API and loads the first round of images

```
$json =  file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/hahanotfunny/media/recent?client_id='. $client_id .'&max_tag_id='. $max_tag_id)  ;
```

Once it goes through the first page of the response, it checks to see if there is another page by grabbing the link in the pagination part of the response. It also checks if there is a value for "max_tag_id" and updates my "max" value in my database. The reason I have a max value is so that when I get a response from "real-time" saying there is new images, I start downloading them from the last max time. However, there is a problem with my code. If we are on the last page of the response (no more pagination link) then there is no "max_tag_id" variable, so there is no update to the database. So, next time my scraper runs it starts with the last known "max_tag_id" and this resulting in duplicate images on the last page being recorded in my database.

So, my question is, when I get another "real-time" alert saying new images are available for a specific tag, how do I find them starting with the last record stored in my database?

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=XXXXXXX;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXX');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function getMax() {
global $dbConnection;

$tag = 'hahanotfunny';
$selectTotals = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM instagram_time WHERE tag = :tag LIMIT 1");
$selectTotals->execute(array(':tag' => $tag));

foreach ($selectTotals as $time) {
    $max = $time['max'];    
}

return $max;
}

function updateMax($data) {
global $dbConnection;

$tag = 'hahanotfunny';
$selectTotals = $dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE instagram_time SET max = :maxid WHERE tag = :tag LIMIT 1");
$selectTotals->execute(array(':maxid' => $data, ':tag' => $tag));
}

function fetchData() {
global $dbConnection, $client_id;

$max_tag_id = getMax();
$json =  file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/hahanotfunny/media/recent?client_id='. $client_id .'&max_tag_id='. $max_tag_id)  ;
$data = json_decode($json);

$next_max = $data->pagination->next_max_tag_id;

foreach ($data->data as $insta) {
    echo '<br/><img  src="'.$insta->images->low_resolution->url.'"/>';

}

foreach ($data as $object) {
    if ( is_array( $object ) ) {
        foreach ( $object as $media ) {
            $url = $media->images->standard_resolution->url;
            $m_id = $media->id;
            $c_time = $media->created_time;
            $user = $media->user->username;
            $filter = $media->filter;
            $comments = $media->comments->count;
            $caption = $media->caption->text;
            $link = $media->link;
            $low_res=$media->images->low_resolution->url;
            $thumb=$media->images->thumbnail->url;
            $lat = $media->location->latitude;
            $long = $media->location->longitude;
            $loc_id = $media->location->id;

            $data = array(
                'media_id' => $m_id,
                'min_id' => $next_min_id,
                'url' => $url,
                'c_time' => $c_time,
                'user' => $user,
                'filter' => $filter,
                'comment_count' => $comments,
                'caption' => $caption,
                'link' => $link,
                'low_res' => $low_res,
                'thumb' => $thumb,
                'lat' => $lat,
                'long' => $long,
                'loc_id' => $loc_id,
            );

            $selectTotals = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO instagram_mg (media_id, min_id, url, c_time, user, filter, comment_count, caption, link, low_res_link, thumb, latitude, longitude, loc_id) VALUES (:mediaid, :minid, :url, :ctime, :user, :filter, :commentcount, :caption, :link, :lowreslink, :thumb, :latitude, :longitude, :locid)");

            $selectTotals->execute(array(':mediaid' => $data['media_id'], ':minid' => $data['min_id'], ':url' => $data['url'], ':ctime' => $data['c_time'], ':user' => $data['user'], ':filter' => $data['filter'], ':commentcount' => $data['comment_count'], ':caption' => $data['caption'], ':link' => $data['link'], ':lowreslink' => $data['low_res'], ':thumb' => $data['thumb'], ':latitude' => $data['lat'], ':longitude' => $data['long'], ':locid' => $data['loc_id']));


        }
    }
}


if (isset($next_max)) {
    echo $next_max . "</br>";
    updateMax($next_max);
    fetchData();
} else {
    //$current_time = time();
    //updateMax($current_time); // i tried making the current time the "max_tag_id" but it wouldnt work. 

}


} //fetchData()


fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a database trigger and accompanying function to check for the duplicates. From mysql.com:

> A trigger is defined to activate when an INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement executes for the associated table. A trigger can be set to activate either before or after the triggering statement. For example, you can have a trigger activate before each row that is inserted into a table or after each row that is updated.

For instance:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_check BEFORE INSERT ON instagram_mg
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    *pseudo-code from here cause I don't know the exacts of mySQL functions*
    if new.media_id is equal to an existing record's media_id, 
        then return false, 
    otherwise, insert the row as normal.
END;
```

Sorry I can't be more specific. I deal mostly in postgreSQL functions and I know the syntax is slightly different. Here's the link to the mySQL trigger syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

I hope this helps. Cheers!